# Creating averaged time-bins from an existing dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, average

I have the following dataframe called 'EasyScaled';

```
str(EasyScaled)
'data.frame':   675045 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Trial           : chr  "1_easy.wav" "1_easy.wav" "1_easy.wav" "1_easy.wav" ...
$ TrialTime       : num  3000 3001 3002 3003 3004 ...
$ PupilBaseCorrect: num  0.784 0.781 0.78 0.778 0.777 ...
```

The 'TrialTime' numeric variable denotes the time of each data point (3000 = 3000ms, 3001 = 3001 ms, etc.), 'PupilBaseCorrect' is my dependent variable, and the 'Trial' variable refers to the experimental trial.

I would like to create a new object which firstly divides my data into 3 time-bins (TimeBin1 = 3000-8000ms, TimeBin2 = 8001-13000ms, TimeBin3 = 13001 - 18000ms) and then calculate an average value for each timebin (for each trial) so that I would end up with something that looks like this (with the value given reflecting 'PupilBaseCorrect');

```
 Trial        TimeBin1     TimeBin2     TimeBin3
 1_easy       0.784        0.876        0.767 
 34_easy      0.781        0.872        0.765
 35_easy      0.78         0.871        0.762 
 ...etc       ...etc       ...etc       ....etc
```

I have tried using cut(), ddply() and some of the suggestions on this blog http://lamages.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/say-it-in-r-with-by-apply-and-friends.html but haven't been able to find the correct code. I also tried this;

```
EasyTimeBin <- aggregate(PupilBaseCorrect ~ Trial + TrialTime[3000:8000, 8001:1300,1301:1800], data=EasyScaled, mean)
```

But got the following error;

```
Error in TrialTime[3000:8000, 8001:1300, 1301:1800] : 
incorrect number of dimensions
```

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want either  

`TrailTime[which(TrailTime %in% c(3000:8000,8001:1300,1301:1800))]`, or take advantage of the `subset` argument in `aggregate`

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'll give that a go if Robert's method below proves tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good use of cut and ddply are correct, but here's some vanilla R chicken scratch that will do what you need.

```
# Generate example data
EasyScaled <- data.frame(
  Trial = paste0(c(sapply(1:3, function(x) rep(x, 9))), "_easy.wav"),
  TrialTime = c(sapply(seq_len(9)-1, function(x) (floor(x/3))*5000 + x%%3 + 3000)),
  PupilBaseCorrect = rnorm(27, 0.78, 0.1)
)

# group means of PupilBaseCorrect by Trial + filename
tmp <- tapply(EasyScaled$PupilBaseCorrect,
    paste0(EasyScaled$Trial, ',',
           as.integer((EasyScaled$TrialTime - 3000)/5000)+1), mean)

# melt & recast the array manually into a dataframe
EasyTimeBin <- do.call(data.frame,
   append(list(row.names = NULL,
               Trial = gsub('.wav,.*','',names(tmp)[3*seq_len(length(tmp)/3)])), 
     structure(lapply(seq_len(3),
         function(x) tmp[3*(seq_len(length(tmp)/3)-1) + x]
       ), .Names = paste0("TimeBin", seq_len(3))
     )
   )
)

print(EasyTimeBin)
#  Trial   TimeBin1  TimeBin2  TimeBin3
# 1 1_easy 0.7471973 0.7850524 0.8939581
# 2 2_easy 0.8096973 0.8390587 0.7757359
# 3 3_easy 0.8151430 0.7855042 0.8081268
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code here Robert, this is very helpful (I would upvote if I could). I just have one question though. Having run this code with my own data, I get a dataframe with 60 rows. However, there should only be 46 as there are only 46 trials. I notice that some trials are duplicated (e.g. 11_easy) and have different values for each duplication. I can't work out why this would be happening though based on your code. Have you got any idea?

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, it looks in the dataframe like every third trial is duplicated, so you get a pattern of rows like this: trial 1, trial 2, trial 3, trial 3, trial 4, trial 5, trial 6, trial 6, and so on..... This is why there are 60 rows instead of 45 (correction from before; there are supposed to be 45 trials, not 46).

Comment: Not sure without the original dataset. An easy hack would be `dataframe <- dataframe[sapply(unique(dataframe$Trial), function(x) which(x == dataframe$Trial)[1]),]`

Comment: Thanks Robert. Unfortunately the mean values that I get in dataframe  don't match up with mean values that I work out when just performing arithmetic on the original 'EasyScaled' dataframe, using; 'mean(EasyScaled$PupilBaseCorrect[1:5000])' etc. I don't understand the code in enough detail to work out where it may be going wrong - I've tried removing "+1" from the #group means section but keep running into the same problem.

Comment: Errors in the new dataframe have the following pattern: the first row in the new dataframe is correct (the "1_easy" trial) but for the next row, the values seem to be shifted to the right so that the correct value for 'timebin1' is actually under 'timebin2', and in the next row the correct value for 'timebin2' is actually under timebin3' etc. This might be frowned upon as being elementary but I'd really appreciate it if you could label each line of code you provided so that I can try to work out how to adjust it appropriately. Thanks for your continued help.